# XGBoost tuning with caret gets worse with number of iterations

Tags: performance, xgboost, caret

When tuning hyperparameters I see that the RMSE gets larger with a greater number of iterations. This is the exact opposite of what I was expecting. Could it be that the data is too noisy for sequential learning trees? My data set is huge with a lot of very small and some very large numbers so I don't think posting a representative sample would be helpful/possible. I am just wondering what is the likely cause for the trend with iterations # that we see in the plots?

[image: RMSE value with number of iterations]

Answer (score 0):

Y-axis decreases with height. The graph is as expected.